What is the standard behavior for await_suspend that returns a handle
Let an Awaiter return a handle, H, in its await_suspend.

I assume it can return a handle to any coroutine.
Let C be the coroutine that awaited the awaiter (co_await Awaiter) what happens next?

Will C execute any code other than H.resume()?

Did you try it yourself?

Yes, seems that given a co_await Awaiter, if Awaiter::await_suspend returns a handle, H, the awaiting coroutine (the one doing co_await) will immediately after completion of Awaiter::await_suspend do H.resume().


Will C execute any code other than H.resume()?

No. If await_suspend returns a coroutine handle, then resume() is immediately called.
[expr.await]/(5.1.1):

If the type of await-suspend is std​::​coroutine_handle<Z>, await-suspend.resume() is evaluated.

